# Открытие html из Assets

Tags: android, java

Имею кучу html файлов в assets. Мне нужно, чтобы по нажатию кнопки открывался один из этих html файлов. Всё равно как: хоть WebView, хоть другой браузер. Даже лучше не через WebView, а через браузер пользователя. 
Есть ли способ открытия напрямую этого html файла? Без WebView? Я перепробовал кучу способов, ни в каком не получалось. Может, вы поможете...

С txt без проблем всё, но мне нужен именно html.

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Вы как-то определитесь, через WebView или через браузер? А то как-то путаетесь в показаниях. Через WebView примерно так:

```
Layout layout=(Layout)findViewById(R.id.addHere); //куда втыкать webView
WebView webView=new WebView(activity);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
webView.loadUrl(urlString); //url ссылка на HTML в ассетах
layout.addView(webView);
```

Через браузер итого проще:

```
Uri uri=Uri.parse(urlString);
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
activity.startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: А что за activity в строке "activity.startActivity(intent);"?

Answer (score 1):

Файлы, которые сложены в каталоге assets вашего приложения доступны "изнутри" по url вида: `file:///android_asset/имя файла.`

Загрузить файл в `WebView` по url можно методом `loadUrl(url)` а чтобы открыть его в браузере, нужно создать `Intent` как `new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, url)` и запустить его методом `startActivity(intent)` из вашего текущего `Activity`